# Does the Fourier coefficients of a function $f\in H^1(0,L)$ (the first order Sobolev space) are absolutely summable?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, fourier-analysis

**My precise question:** Let $f\in H^1(0,L)$ and let $\{f_n\}$ be its Fourier sine series coefficients on $(0,L)$, is it true that $\{f_n\}\in l^1$, i.e. $$\sum_{n}|f_n|< \infty .$$
Thanks

Comment: no in general no, fourier coefficients are not generaly absolute convergent or do not have $L^1$ norm (but have $L^2$ norm)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fact that $f$ is in $H^1$ implies that its derivative $Df$ is in $L^2$.  The Fourier coefficients of $Df$ are (up to a constant)  $\{n |f_n|\}$. The Parseval relationship then implies that $ \{n |f_n|\} \in \ell_2$.

Since $ \{n |f_n|\} \in \ell_2$ the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality implies

\begin{align*}
 \sum_n |f_n| 
&= 
 \sum_n n^{-1} n |f_n| \\
&\leq 
\left( \sum_n n^{-2} \right)^{1/2}\left( \sum_n  n^2 |f_n|^2  \right)^{1/2}\\
&<\infty
\end{align*}

Comment: Thanks a lot! I am just wondering if you can guide me how/where I can find the proof of the statement "$f\in H^1$ implies $\{n |f_n|\}\in l_2$.